# What is SilentPrint ahead of main url?

Tags: javascript, django

Currently I am not able to load my website page in firefox because of silentprint preceding ahead of main url.
My website working perfectly in chrome browser but in firefox only I am getting error because of silentprint.

**.js file**

```
var manaulPrintURL =  "SilentPrint:"+ printURL;
$(this).attr('href', manaulPrintURL);
document.getElementById(this.id).click();
```

After loading website in firefox my url become like 
"silentprint:http://192.168.1.192:8010/test/419/" & getting error saying as below screenshot.[image: silentprint_error]

Why I am getting above kind of problem only when using firefox browser & what will be solution of it.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. "SilentPrint" is there before the URL because you explicitly put it there.

Comment: Actually that was old code done by my previous employee & now I do not know how does it works. I am getting error & I need to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like by using `silenprint` ahead of url , you can print page directly from printer without using `ctrl + p` command.

Have you tried to print it and if getting any error please share trackback.